# How to use GetFileSecurity to check if the current user has write access to a directory in nsis?

Tags: windows, security, nsis

Nsis installer needs to check the folder write access permission before proceeding with the installation, How to achieve this?
I read online about GetFileSecurity, Could anyone please let me know how to use this win api?